# C# app domain exception when "AddPermission", saying absolute path is require?

Tags: c#, security, exception, dns

I was just trying app domain and have this code:

```
        var perm = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
        perm.AddPermission(
            new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
        perm.AddPermission( // exception
            new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.NoAccess, "@d:\\"));
```

In fact the line "new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.NoAccess, "@d:\"));" throws exception, saying:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Absolute path information is required.
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
```

Where did I get wrong, how to fix it?

Comment: Look at the path you have provided `"@d:\\"`, it should be `@"d:\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the path in the wrong way.
change this "@d:\" to @"d:\" to make the string verbatim.

```
"@d:\\" -> @d:\
@"d:\"  -> d:\
```

[More Info About String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8)